# How and when to use the articles?

Tags: grammar

Why we don’t use the article *a* after the preposition *to* in this phrase?

> He went to prison.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer and see if it tells you waht you want to know: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a

Comment: It is completely acceptable to say "He went to a prison and decided to stay there."

Comment: With an article it would mean something different. To go to prison is to be sentenced. To go to a prison is to travel there -- people who got to prison have to go to a prison, as do the employees, visitors, deliverypeople, etc. This construction borders on being a phrasal verb. Much like going to jail or going to prison, a person can go to college or go to university or go to beauty school or go to night school.

Comment: Another useful link : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67036/how-do-american-english-and-british-english-use-the-definite-article-differently